# HTML & CSS Div Class's not joining

Tags: html, css, layout

I am making the header of the website and I have already came across a problem. I'm horrible with layout so I need some help. Below is my markup and stylesheet:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Homepage</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>

<body bgcolor="#C2C2C2">

<div class="header">
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="logo.png">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="menubar">
    <h1>Menu</h1>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

.header {
    background-color:#1D1D1D;
    margin:20px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    padding:15px;
    color:white;
    font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888888;
}

.menubar {
    background-color:#434343;
    margin:20px;
    margin-top:0px;
    padding:0px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888888;
    color:white;
    font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;
}

.logo {
    right:0px;
}
```

What I want is for the header and the menu bar to join together like this image below:
[image: Header Image]
Where the menu bar will sit just underneath of the header.
Please help me, this is really frustrating me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your stylesheet:

```
h1 {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Your `h1` element was pushing it down.

You can also add a CSS Reset stylesheet, that will make browsers render all elements more consistently and in line with modern standards, such as `normalize.css`:
http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/